# How to set initial player health to a custom value in Roblox Studio?

Tags: roblox

My goal is to have an initial/max custom player health for my Roblox place in Roblox Studio.

To do this I have created a script in `StarterPlayer/StarterPlayerScript` with the following content:

```
local DEFAULT_HEALTH = 10

game.Players.PlayerAdded:connect(function(player)
    player.character.Humanoid.MaxHealth = DEFAULT_HEALTH
    player.character.Humanoid.Health = DEFAULT_HEALTH
end)
```

I have also tried with:

```
local DEFAULT_HEALTH = 10

local Character = script.Parent
local Humanoid = Character:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
Humanoid.MaxHealth = DEFAULT_HEALTH
Humanoid.Health = DEFAULT_HEALTH
```

in both cases when I playtest it (`TEST->PLAY`) it seems the default **health=100** is used instead of **health=10**

**Is it possible to fix the issue outlined?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PlayerAdded event fires as soon as the player joins the server, but their character model doesn't load into the world immediately. So you need to wait for the player's character model to spawb. Luckily, you can use the CharacterAdded event to know when that happens.

So using a Script in the Workspace or ServerScriptService, try this :

```lua
local DEFAULT_HEALTH = 10

game.Players.PlayerAdded:connect(function(player)
    player.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(character)
        character.Humanoid.MaxHealth = DEFAULT_HEALTH
        character.Humanoid.Health = DEFAULT_HEALTH
    end)
end)
```